# Update with subquery failing due to multiple rows being returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have tried this:

```sql
update iclock_transaction set inout=(select(b.rno%2)  from (
select emp_code,Row_number() over( Partition by emp_code,convert (date,punch_time) order by punch_time )as rno from iclock_transaction)b)
```

I got the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: When you got the message *"Title cannot contain "SQL Update Query not working". Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"* that wasn't an excuse to make the title contain a typographical error to around the error...

Comment: The error, here, is telling you the problem; your subquery is returning multiple values, and that isn't allowed in that content. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Just run the `query` without `update` part and you will see that it returns multiple rows as a result. That is what error is suggesting. You cannot have multiple returns in an update query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the subquery, you can update a derived table directly.

Looks like you actually need this

```sql
update ict
set inout = ict.rno % 2
from (
    select
      ict.*,
      Row_number() over (Partition by ict.emp_code, convert(date, ict.punch_time) order by ict.punch_time ) as rno
    from iclock_transaction ict
) ict;
```